# Mouse for rotation

Tags: camera, rotation

I would like to know how you do handle mouse contoll.

As known from many games, if I want to rotate my Camera, the mouse is generally locked. For example shooter games do that.

But how to detect then, were the mouse moves, if it is blocked to move?

I don't get that logic.

I hope someone can help me. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my scene, I don't disable the mouse, I just disable the cursor.

```
glfwSetInputMode(renderer::get_window(), GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED);
```

This is done when I initialise the scene.

Then when I move the mouse, I check what it's doing in my update section (which is called every frame)

```
static double ratio_width = quarter_pi<float>() / static_cast<float>(renderer::get_screen_width());
static double ratio_height = (quarter_pi<float>() * (static_cast<float>(renderer::get_screen_height()) / static_cast<float>(renderer::get_screen_width()))) / static_cast<float>(renderer::get_screen_height());

double current_x = 0;
double current_y = 0;

glfwGetCursorPos(renderer::get_window(), &current_x, &current_y);

double delta_x = current_x - prev_x;
double delta_y = current_y - prev_y;

delta_x *= ratio_width;
delta_y *= ratio_height;

cam.rotate(delta_x, -delta_y);

prev_x = current_x;
prev_y = current_y;
```

Of course you need more than that for physical movement, like pitch, yaw, etc. But these are the basics.

So a position is set to (0,0) - the centre every frame, we measure the mouse's movement away from it and then move the camera by that amount. Then when a new frame comes it is reset again but at this point we do not move the camera, only the cursor position. Or rather, that's what we're effectively doing.

Sorry, I think I didn't explain that last bit very well, hopefully my code is more useful. It's C++ with some OpenGL related libraries like glew32.

Comment: Now it works :D  I just edited some lines. Now I'm reseting the Mouse Cursor each frame to the center. It works much better, I had it before. Wow. Thank you so much. I already had yaw and pitch implemented by the way. Have a nice day :D